# Leaving editor on number makes many duplicates across the screen

Tags: vim

As you can see by my weak title, I'm not sure how to best describe this issue, and thus have had no luck searching for the answer.  If a dupe exists, I'll remove this; please point me to it.

My problem comes after I am finished editing in vim.  With my cursor (red line) placed on a number that I've just entered or edited into the code, like this:

[image]

When I go to write and quit using `:wq`, the editor occasionally has a mind of its own and decides I really wanted a LOT MORE 4s in that code and promptly adds in its own like this:

[image]

I really only wanted `$x` to be `44`.  But vim seems to want to make the choice for me.

I have had this issue on numerous machines, though all were running Ubuntu as far as I can remember.

Anyone else have this issue?  Any solve?  Bug?

**EDIT:**

I'm posting the scriptout recording below:

```
<80>kd<80>kd<80>kdi^M^M<80>ku  $x = 55;^[i<80>kl55^[:q<80>kb<80>kb<80>kr<80>kr55i55`<80>kb`<80>kb^[:q!^M
```

This shows me trying to get it to explode two or three times.  Finally on the last time, it went from `$x = 55555;` to something like:

```
$x = 55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555;
```

During one test last night, it went from about 40 '4's to around 200.

I was hoping this was a known issue.  I'm starting to think it may be OS related.  Even though I've tried this on multiple dev machines they are all running a similar VM.  Might be something I've done somewhere else.  Thank you for trying.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior if you start vim with vimrc and plugins disabled? Try `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` and see if you still see the problem. Check also if you have any autocmd's for quitting, with `:autocmd QuitPre`, does that list any?

Comment: Many thanks for the comment.  No auto cmds, no.  I can try to disable those plugins.  Unfortunately, the behavior seems very unpredictable - I can't reproduce consistently, so I will have to do quite a few tests to see if successful.  But I will, and will report back.

Comment: Another idea is to start Vim with [`vim -w scriptout`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-w) (or `-W`) to record all keystrokes. If the problem happens, see if you can reproduce it consistently with the last few keystrokes and the file you were editing at the same version. Rationale: the sequence of characters looks like a repetition command, such as `12i44`, or `yl25p`, so recording keystrokes should help you see whether you were inadvertently typing a count you didn't realize, or if a key sequence is being incorrectly recognized as a count...

Comment: In any case, if by recording the keystrokes you manage to produce a reproducible case, you can then experiment with disabling plug-ins etc. to figure out what might be causing this.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden my guess is similar: i used to sometimes type the number, forget to hit insert, than hit i. When i escape’d it would explode like this.

Comment: Well.. I was able to reproduce after quite a bit of testing.  Both when using the NONE flags above, as well as when I recorded keystrokes.  It happened both times.  So even with no plugins, it still happened.  And, according to the record log, I did NOT type the extra 4444s, but they exploded nonetheless.   I'll keep trying tomorrow, but thank you both for your help.

Comment: can you post the record log? There are other ways in vim to insert a `4` twelve times than typing it twelve times

Comment: For those who may be lazy to count, there are exactly 46 digits, e.g. 44 digits + the original text.

Comment: Posted the recording.  Thank you all, but I think this is probably something on my end rather than a bug we can figure out.  If no one else has this issue, it's likely me.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while (didn't get a notification from your comment.) I have now posted an answer. It turns out you *were* using the number as a count and the recording is there to show it . I have detailed it all in my answer, please take a look! (cc @D.BenKnoble who also brought up the repeat count and who can also call me out if I'm incorrect in my analysis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your recording, it's clear you're using `55` as a count at one point. Let me break this down and show you what is happening.

First, let's replace keystrokes for special keys with more readable names:

- `<80>kr`: `<Right>` (similarly, `kl`, `ku` and `kd` represent left, up and down)
- `<80>kb`: `<BS>` (Backspace key)
- `^[`: `<Esc>`
- `^M`: `<CR>` (the ENTER or RETURN key)

Now let's look at this snippet at the end:

```
<Right><Right>55i55`<BS>`<BS><Esc>:q!
```

See the `55` in bold? That's being used as a count. So it's inserting `55`, 55 times.

Let's break it down:

- `<Right><Right>`: You're moving the cursor. Note that you're in **NORMAL** mode here, since right before these motions you typed `:q` and then `<BS>` twice, deleting the `q` and the `:` and going back to normal mode.
- `55`: That's a count! You probably thought you were in insert mode, but you were not. Since you didn't see anything, you proceeded to:
- `i`: Go to insert mode. But note you're under the `55` count at this point!
- `55`: Enter number 55, as expected.
- `` `<BS> ``: You typed this twice. I imagine you were reaching out for the Escape key and hit `` ` `` instead. Then you backspaced over it to remove it.
- `<Esc>`: Finally leaving insert mode. **The insertion will expand 55 times at this point!**
- `:q!`: Quitting.

So you're actually using the number as a count, without realizing it.

### What can you do about it?

There are a few things you can do to realize you're about to repeat an operation unexpectedly. A few ways you can improve your life here.

1. You can start by enabling [`set showcmd`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27) in your vimrc. This will show you the (normal mode) command you're typing on the last line and you will be able to see the keystrokes that are pending. In that case, when you type `55` in normal mode and don't see it inserted (because you're not in insert mode), you'll be able to see that the `55` is pending and when you execute an operation (such as `i` for inserting) it will have a count which will cause it to repeat.
2. Check your settings for [`'timeout'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27), [`'ttimeout'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ttimeout%27) and also [`'timeoutlen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27), [`'ttimeoutlen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ttimeoutlen%27). These might affect how long from when you hit `<Esc>` at the end of insert mode until the count actually has an effect. This might make you perceive the problem as happening when you're quitting (when you hit `:` from `:q`) rather than what happens before then. If you have insert mode mappings that include the `<Esc>` key (or a special key sequence that happens to start with `<Esc>` in your scenario, F-keys are a common example of keys possibly mapped to sequences starting with `<Esc>`), this might make the problem worse. Make sure timeouts are enabled and tune the timeout lengths down so you have quicker feedback of what's happening.
3. Finally, look into using a status line plug-in such as [lightline.vim](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) or [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). These plug-ins will help you see whether you're in normal or insert mode, by switching the color of the whole status bar to give you a very strong visual cue to which state you're on at the moment. This might be able to help you realize you still need to switch to insert mode before you can start inserting numbers. (The built-in option [`'showmode'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showmode%27), which is enabled by default, can also help with some of that feedback, though it doesn't print anything for Normal mode, only the other modes, and is a lot more subtle in its output, so it's easier to miss than a status line changing colors.)

Hopefully these will help improve your current situation!

### Why I think you're hitting this.

Looking at your recording, I can also tell you I have an idea of why you've been having this issue...

I see you're using arrow keys to move around, rather than `hjkl` and other more efficient movement commands in normal mode (`w`, `4w`, `t)`, `}`, `]}`, etc.) And you seem to be using the arrow keys both in normal and in insert mode (they work in either mode after all!)

This results into a situation where **your motion commands work the same in normal and insert mode**. So, in your mind, the distinction between normal and insert mode gets blurred and consequently you're not in a mindset where you can quickly tell yourself whether you're in normal or insert mode (since they act the same to some extent.)

That's probably why you're trying to insert text while in normal mode, while not noticing that you're doing it. Because, in your mind, you might as well have been in insert mode!

I would recommend that you try to change these habits, for two reasons:

- While using Vim, it's better if in your mind it's clear to you which mode you're in. (That will help you stop making mistakes related to the mode you're in, such as the one in this question.)
- You get more efficient using Vim if you learn to use more efficient motions (`w`, `4w`, `t)`, `}`, `]}`, etc.) rather than the single line/column motions (`hjkl`, or arrow keys...)

Stop using the arrow keys is a first step towards both.

Some people recommend disabling the arrow keys. You can do that in normal mode only, or in both normal and insert mode, if you'd like to force yourself to go back to normal mode when you want to move around. That is also a good practice. You can use `inoremap <Left> <Nop>` and similar for the other keys to disable them in insert mode, and the equivalent `noremap` to disable them in normal and visual mode.

It's of course, up to you... If you like using the arrow keys to move, they *do* work and you can keep using Vim that way... But if you do want to try the other way around, I can say there are benefits to that approach. Vim is a modal editor for some reason, using the modes effectively (and more efficient motion keys in normal mode) *can* improve your efficiency in Vim.

If you do prefer simplicity and would like to use arrow keys, you might want to consider [easy mode](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#easy), in which Vim is *always* kept in insert mode and using the arrow keys (and PgUp, PgDown, etc.) is how you're supposed to move around. In other words, turning Vim into a non-modal editor. It's a valid approach.

I hope these suggestions are helpful to you! Hopefully you'll at least be able to tune your Vim environment so that you'll *notice* when you're using a number as a count, or at least get better/quicker feedback when that happens, so you can fix that more quickly.

Comment: Holy cow - this is one of the best constructed and most helpful answers I've seen on SO.  AND, it totally solves my problem.  The problem being *me* btw ;)  I have been doing this for years and years - I only use vim for quick changes on a dev server, and so never took the time to investigate till now.  I think I'll take your advice and remove the arrow keys functionality.   Sincerely appreciate this fantastic answer!

Comment: @Watercayman I'm so glad you found this helpful and also happy that we got to the bottom of it! Your feedback is also really appreciated. (Reason I hang out here is I enjoy helping people, so knowing that I did is always great!)

Comment: Great feedback on the arrow keys. Only thing I’d add is that `showmode` can replace the mode-functionality of a statusline plugin (and, since I handbuilt mine, I care)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Updated the answer to include a reference to `'showmode'`. Thanks for the suggestion!